# Make a shell script a dependency

Tags: cmake

I have an `ExternalProject_Add` with a `PATCH_COMMAND bash patch_script.sh`. The problem is that cmake doesn't rebuild when patch_script.sh changes.

How can I tell CMake that when patch_script.sh changes then this project is modified?

patch_script.sh invokes patch with several patch files. It would be great if I could make the project depend on them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the CMake forum. Looks like this is not yet possible but a change is coming.

https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-make-changes-to-scripts-and-patch-files-used-in-patch-command-rebuild-externalproject/8666